# What does it mean to extend a prototype with a new function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript-objects

I have created a constructor function:

```
function Application(fullName,age,contactInfo){
  this.fullName= fullName;
  this.age= age;
  this.contactInfo= contactInfo;
}
```

I am trying to define a new function `newFunction` and to have it "extend" the `Application` prototype. `newFunction` should return the `age + 1` for the `Application` it was called on.

What does "extend" mean? Is it a function? Do I call the objects as an array on my `newFunction`?

Comment: Have you taken a look on `MSN`? Here is a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to constructors and you hear "extend" you can think of "make". But generally we don't say "make" because it sounds like you have to create something from scratch. When you have something existing (the constructor) and you are asked to add something to it like `newFunction`, "extend" is a better word for it.

So likely you are asked to make a new prototype function for `Application`. For example after your constructor code example you posted, if you are asked to

- extend the Application prototype with a function `sayMyName`
- takes no parameters
- that always produces an alert of `My name is:`, followed by `fullName`, you could do:

```js
Application.prototype.sayMyName = function() {
  alert("My name is: " + this.name);
};
```

Any objects instantiated using `Application` constructor, you can now call a `.sayMyName();` method to produce the `My name is...` alert .

So with this as an example, hopefully you now know what to do for your situation.

Comment: Thanks you so much, still working on it, got to figure it out before midnight D: but your example really helped. Thanks again.